# Subclassing WPF UserControl doesn't work across projects

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

Hi I've created some subclassed usercontrols based upon the information found here ; http://csharpsimplified.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/subclassing-wpf-user-control/ but I'm hitting a problem.

Here's my base class held in a TestUserControl project.

```
namespace TestUserControl
{
    public class BaseDataGridControl : UserControl
    {
        protected BaseDataGridControl()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my concrete class ;

```
<view:BaseDataGridControl x:Class="TestUserControl.Concrete"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:view="clr-namespace:TestUserControl"      
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="20" Width="60" Margin="12,12,228,268" />
    </Grid>
</view:BaseDataGridControl>
```

and this controls code behind looks like this ;

```
public partial class Concrete : BaseDataGridControl
{
    public Concrete()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I can drop my concrete class on a window in the same TestUserControl project without any problems ;

```
<Window x:Class="TestUserControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:TestUserControl">
    <Grid>
        <my:Concrete HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,39,0,0" x:Name="concrete1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

this all works fine.

The problem is when I attempt to use the concrete class in another project.

If I create another project (WPFApplication1) and create a class based upon the concrete class e.g.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class SubClass : Concrete
    {
    }
}
```

when i attempt to drop this onto a window in the WPFApplication1 project I get an ;

"The enumerator is not valid because the collection changed"

If I try to add it via XAML I get a

'The component 'WpfApplication1.SubClass' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/TestUserControl;component/concrete.xaml'.

error message.

The WPFApplication1 project has a reference to the TestUserControl project.

Does anybody have any clues why this works within the project the usercontrol was defined in, but as soon as you attempt to subclass it in a separate project it fails?

I've tried this in VS2010 and VS11 beta with the same bad results.

I'm not using reflection or accessing any collections in the constructors of the classes, the code is what you see here.

I've got test project that demonstrates this problem, if it would help?

Thanks ....

Comment: sample project can be downloaded from https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=150630a5c1433bff&resid=150630A5C1433BFF!120&parid=root

Comment: Did you try.. public _partial_ class SubClass : Concrete ?

Comment: I did but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem. I have a project with my base UI in it, and a few items are user controls. (We'll call this project "BaseUI"). In my second project (We'll call it "SubProj") I can add the references for it and add it to the xaml in Visual Studio just fine, but I can't use Blend to see the the changes. And now I can't use it for some of my more complex editing.

It produces the error "[component name goes here] does not exist in the namespace [your referenced namespace]"

The fix that I found will probably allow you to inherit from it as well in your sub project.

Instead of attempting to use the class directly from the referenced assembly, you can add the code into your current assembly using a link. The link causes the control to act as if it was in the existing project, however the code is from the base project. Any changes to it affects all links. You should be able to inherit from that locally without the issues of going across projects.

Here's how you do it:

1. Create the base control in your "BaseUI" project
2. Right click your "SubProj" and add an existing item
3. Hunt down the .xaml file from the "BaseUI" project for the user control you want.
4. Click the arrow next to the "Add" button and choose "Add as link"